best way to whiteboard during meetings? I have an iPad pro
I used to airdrop a Google Jamboard link to my iPad pro, open the app from there and use it as whiteboard, while screensharing the window from my laptop so that recordings can capture it as well (and others don't have to open the whiteboard app).
But now Google has sunset Jamboard, I haven't been able to find a good alternative. Freeform unfortunately doesn't have a laser pointer, and I sometimes don't write within the frame of what is screenshared so it's not been useful
